# How to append list values to a URL in Python

Tags: python

I have a base url that I would like to append list values to so that I have a list of URLs to scrape. My list comes from a json file, and looks like:

```
[{u'url': [u'/location/subfile/file1.htm', u'/location/subfile/file2.htm', u'/location/subfile/file3.htm', u'/location/subfile/file4.htm']}]
```

My base URL is something like `http://example.com/placeforfiles/`

What I want, ultimately, is a collection of URLs that have that base URL plus the list values, like so:

```
http://example.com/placeforfiles/location/subfile/file1.htm
http://example.com/placeforfiles/location/subfile/file2.htm
http://example.com/placeforfiles/location/subfile/file3.htm
http://example.com/placeforfiles/location/subfile/file4.htm
```

There may be thousands of list values I need to append, so I know I need to loop through them and append them but I haven't found a solution that works. I'm currently trying:

```
import json

with open ('returned_items.json') as links:
    data = json.load(links)

base_url = 'http://example.com/placeforfiles/{}'

for i in data:
    url = 'http://example.com/placeforfiles/{}'.format(i)
    print url
```

Which is returning:

```
http://example.com/placeforfiles/({u'url': [u'/location/subfile/file1.htm', u'/location/subfile/file2.htm', u'/location/subfile/file3.htm', u'/location/subfile/file4.htm']},)
```

Comment: Sorry, just realized that was in there by accident I edited the question to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because the dict is the first element in the array. 
The loop should be `for i in data[0]["url"]`

Answer (score 1):

```
#replcace data with below line
data = json.loads(links)

#replace your last loop with below
if data and 'url' in data[0]:
 for i in data[0]['url']:
  url = 'http://example.com/placeforfiles{}'.format(i)
  print(url)
```